# How to check whether a group of elements is disabled in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I am creating a page object that needs to have a function to check whether a group of elements is disabled.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
areAllElementsDisabled: function (allElements) {
        return allElements.filter(function (elem) {
            return elem.isEnabled().then(function (isEnabled) {
                return isEnabled;
            });
        }).length===0;
    }
```

Can anybody suggest a way to solve the issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is stuck with a similar problem, I have found a way that works for me:

```
areAllElementsDisabled: function (allElements) {
            var allElemetsPromises = allElements.map(function(elem){
                return elem.isEnabled();
            });

            return Promise.all(allElemetsPromises).then(function(values){
                return values.every(function(value){
                    return !value;
                })
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `count()` on filtered elements to make code more simple:

```
areAllElementsDisabled: function (allElements) {
    return allElements.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.isEnabled();
    }).count(function(cnt){
        return cnt === 0;
    });
}
```